# How to best save a HDR series on D7000?

Tags: hdr, nikon-d7000

I tend to take several photos of different EVs for my HDR compositions but when processing them on my computer I often get confused as to which pictures relate to which HDR series.

I'm wondering if there's a way for the D7000 to automatically collate and group photos when in autobracketing mode or if there's a way to manually do it when I manually change the EVs for each photo in the series?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's obviously nowhere near automatic, you can always just take a photo of your hand (or anything else suitably distinctive) between each series.

Comment: Haha, fair enough, sometimes ultra basic works best!